# Python: Minimum Sum Sublist of an Integer

Tags: python, sum, max, minimum, sublist

Python Trouble:
I am having so much trouble on how to approach this program. Can someone help me or at least give me a hint on what this program is asking?

5.37 Write function mssl() (minimum sum sublist) that takes as input a list of integers.
It then computes and returns the sum of the maximum sum sublist of the input list. The
maximum sum sublist is a sublist (slice) of the input list whose sum of entries is largest.
The empty sublist is defined to have sum 0. For example, the maximum sum sublist of the
list.

```
[4, -2, -8, 5, -2, 7, 7, 2, -6, 5]
is [5, -2, 7, 7, 2] and the sum of its entries is 19.
>>> l = [4, -2, -8, 5, -2, 7, 7, 2, -6, 5]
>>> mssl(l)
19
>>> mssl([3,4,5])
12
>>> mssl([-2,-3,-5])
0
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be in?

Comment: It's supposed to be in Python, I had it in the title.

Comment: Ah-ha so you did - must remember to get myself glasses at some point :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are asked to find all possible sublists of your list. Given your list is `[3,4,5]`, all possible sublists are:

```
[]
[3]
[3,4]
[3,4,5]
[4]
[4,5]
[5]
```

You can do this using a nested [loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
l = your_list
for start in xrange(len(l)):
  for end in xrange(1, len(l)+1):
    current_sublist = l[start:end]
```

Next, you are tasked to find the maximum sum of any of those sublists. One way is to create a local variable update it in the loop if the sum of the current sublist is greater than any sum before. Let's also wrap it into a function:

```
def mssl(l):
  f = 0
  for start in xrange(len(l)):
    for end in xrange(1, len(l)+1):
      s = sum(l[start:end]) 
      if s > f: 
        f = s
  return f
```

---

Let's test it:

```
print mssl([4, -2, -8, 5, -2, 7, 7, 2, -6, 5])
print mssl([3,4,5])
print mssl([-2,-3,-5])
```

Output:

```
19
12
0
```

---

one-liner for good measure:

```
l = [4, -2, -8, 5, -2, 7, 7, 2, -6, 5]
max(sum(l[s:e]) for s in xrange(len(l)) for e in xrange(1, len(l)+1))
```